# stm32f4 CAN receiver_IT issue

Tags: c, stm32, can-bus, hal

Next in my little project(stm32f407vg) is to receive can messages from another hardware(PIC 18L25K80)

I currently have working an UART to my computer so I can easily debug the chip via UART.

The problem is that I receive the message, the interruption gets triggered but what I read from rxMessage is non sense.

Test Procedure:

Simulating the emitter I use Microchip CAN BUS Analayzer, here is the screenshot of the window:
[image]

And here is what I see in the UART:
[image]

And this is what I see if I debug (I'm using Coocox 1.7.8):
[image]

Why the values of rxMessage doesn't change neither inside the HAL driver or in my code (can.c).

Thanks.

---------------------------- main.c-------------------------

```
#include "globals.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "syscfg.h"
#include "can.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"

#include "kernel.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    SysIniCfg();

    while (1){

        kernelMotor();
        usartMotor();
        canMotor();

        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_G_GPIO_Port,LED_G_Pin);

    }
}
```

------------------------- end main.c -----------------------

---------------------------- syscfg.c-------------------------

```
#include "syscfg.h"
#include "syscfg.h"
#include "can.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"
#include "kernel.h"

/*
 * System Init configuration
 */

void SysIniCfg(){

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();
    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();
    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_CAN1_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    /* Initialize interrupts */
    MX_NVIC_Init();
    kernelInit();
}
```

------------------------- end syscfg.c -----------------------

---------------------------- can.h-------------------------

```
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "globals.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* USER CODE BEGIN Private defines */
typedef struct
{

    CAN_HandleTypeDef       Handle;

    HAL_CAN_StateTypeDef    *pState;

    uint32_t                *pErrorCode;

} t_can_control;

typedef enum{
    CM_STOPPED = 0,
    CM_INIT = 1,
    CM_IDLE = 10,
    CM_ERROR = 255

}uint8_t_canStates;

uint8_t_canStates canMotorStates;

extern CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan1;

t_can_control can_ctrl;
CanTxMsgTypeDef sTxMsg;
CanRxMsgTypeDef sRxMsg;

/* USER CODE END Private defines */
/* USER CODE BEGIN Prototypes */
extern void Error_Handler(void);

void MX_CAN1_Init(void);
```

------------------------- end can.h -----------------------

---------------------------- can.c-------------------------

```
#include "can.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan1;

/* CAN1 init function */
void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{
    CAN_FilterConfTypeDef sFilterConfig;

    canMotorStates = CM_STOPPED;

    hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
    hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 20;
    hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
    hcan1.Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
    hcan1.Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_13TQ;
    hcan1.Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
    hcan1.Init.TTCM = DISABLE;
    hcan1.Init.ABOM = DISABLE;
    hcan1.Init.AWUM = DISABLE;
    hcan1.Init.NART = DISABLE;
    hcan1.Init.RFLM = DISABLE;
    hcan1.Init.TXFP = DISABLE;

    if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK){
        Error_Handler();
    }

    sFilterConfig.FilterNumber = 0;
    sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
    sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_16BIT;
    sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
    sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
    sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
    sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
    sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
    sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
    sFilterConfig.BankNumber = 14;

    if(HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK){
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

void HAL_CAN_MspInit(CAN_HandleTypeDef* canHandle)
{

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    if(canHandle->Instance==CAN1)
    {
        /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_MspInit 0 */

        /* USER CODE END CAN1_MspInit 0 */
        /* Peripheral clock enable */
        __HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLE();

        /**CAN1 GPIO Configuration
    PA11     ------> CAN1_RX
    PA12     ------> CAN1_TX 
         */
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_CAN1;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_MspInit 1 */
        canMotorStates = CM_INIT;
        /* USER CODE END CAN1_MspInit 1 */
    }
}

void HAL_CAN_MspDeInit(CAN_HandleTypeDef* canHandle)
{

    if(canHandle->Instance==CAN1)
    {
        /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_MspDeInit 0 */

        /* USER CODE END CAN1_MspDeInit 0 */
        /* Peripheral clock disable */
        __HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_DISABLE();

        /**CAN1 GPIO Configuration
    PA11     ------> CAN1_RX
    PA12     ------> CAN1_TX 
         */
        HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12);

        /* Peripheral interrupt Deinit*/
        HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(CAN1_TX_IRQn);
        HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(CAN1_RX0_IRQn);
        HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(CAN1_RX1_IRQn);
        HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(CAN1_SCE_IRQn);

    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_MspDeInit 1 */
    canMotorStates = CM_STOPPED;
    /* USER CODE END CAN1_MspDeInit 1 */
} 


/**
 * @brief  Sends order for reading and reads an amount of data in no-blocking mode with Interrupt.
 * @param  u8can: Number of CAN instance
 * @param  u16std_id: CAN standard identifier
 * @param   pstate: Pointer to CAN state
 * @param   pu32error: Pointer to CAN error code
 * @retval HAL status
 */
HAL_StatusTypeDef CAN_Read_wInt(uint8_t u8can, uint16_t u16std_id, HAL_CAN_StateTypeDef *pstate, uint32_t *pu32error){

    HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_OK;

        if ((*pu32error) == HAL_CAN_ERROR_NONE)
        {
            /* Set Rx Message structure */
            sRxMsg.StdId = (uint32_t)u16std_id;
            sRxMsg.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
            sRxMsg.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
            sRxMsg.DLC = (uint8_t)8;
            sRxMsg.FIFONumber = CAN_FIFO0;
            sRxMsg.FMI = 1;

            /* Put structure in the handle */
            can_ctrl.Handle.pRxMsg = &sRxMsg;

            /* Order to transmit in non-blocking mode */
            status = HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(&hcan1, CAN_FIFO0);

            if (status == HAL_OK)
            {
                /* Link external pointers to CAN local pointer */
                can_ctrl.pState        = pstate;
                can_ctrl.pErrorCode = pu32error;
                /* Update CAN State */
                *(can_ctrl.pState)  = HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_RX;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            status = HAL_BUSY;
        }

    return status;

}

void HAL_CAN_RxCpltCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef* CanHandle)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_Y_GPIO_Port,LED_Y_Pin);
    char canOutBuffer[100];
    sprintf(canOutBuffer,"-- %d : %d --", CanHandle->pRxMsg->StdId,CanHandle->pRxMsg->Data[0]);
    usartPutString(canOutBuffer);

    if(HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(CanHandle, CAN_FIFO0) != HAL_OK){
        Error_Handler();
    }
}
```

------------------------- end can.c -----------------------

---------------------------- main.c-------------------------
------------------------- end main.c -----------------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was missing, in the definition of the can handle was specified the tx and rx message, so I suppose that the HAL drivers didn't do the initialization of this structures

```
 void MX_CAN1_Init(void) {
        CAN_FilterConfTypeDef sFilterConfig;
```

> static CanTxMsgTypeDef TxMessage;
>
> static CanRxMsgTypeDef RxMessage;

```
        canMotorStates = CM_STOPPED;

        hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
        hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 20;
        hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
        hcan1.Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
        hcan1.Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_13TQ;
        hcan1.Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
        hcan1.Init.TTCM = DISABLE;
        hcan1.Init.ABOM = DISABLE;
        hcan1.Init.AWUM = DISABLE;
        hcan1.Init.NART = DISABLE;
        hcan1.Init.RFLM = DISABLE;
        hcan1.Init.TXFP = DISABLE;
```

> hcan1.pRxMsg = &RxMessage;
>
> hcan1.pTxMsg = &TxMessage;

```
        if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }

        sFilterConfig.FilterNumber = 0;
        sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
        sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_16BIT;
        sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
        sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
        sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
        sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
        sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
        sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
        sFilterConfig.BankNumber = 14;

        if(HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
        {
            /* Filter configuration Error */
            Error_Handler();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about this missing code?

Comment: What kind of explanation do you want? I get to the solution because I saw that in the definition of the can handle was specified the tx and rx message, so I suppose that the HAL drivers didn't do the initialization of this structures.

Comment: It would be fine if you could include your comment into the answer. It was not obvious why was these changes necessary.